# Basic Python Function and Constant Help

Tags: python, function, constants

I'm not sure where to even start this assignment:

In shopping for a new house, you must consider several factors. In this problem the initial cost of the house, the estimated annual fuel costs, and the annual tax rate are available. Write a program that determines and displays the total cost of a house after a five-year period and execute the program for each of the following sets of data:

```
Initial House Cost  Annual Fuel Cost  Tax Rate
167,000             3,300             0.025
162,000             3,500             0.025
175,000             2,850             0.025
```

To calculate the house cost, add the initial cost to the fuel cost for five years, then add the taxes for five years. Taxes for one year are computed by multiplying the tax rate by the initial cost. Show testing for your program as discussed in lab and lecture.

Any help with writing the initial function and the constants would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should try hacking something out and figure out a more specific question.  If you can get to the point where you have some code, even if it's not working at all, people can probably give you more helpful pointers.  At this point, we don't know if you even know what a function is, or if you can do basic math.

Comment: I personally believe Stackoverflow shouldn't be the place where you put your homework for other people to solve. However if you do so, please have even the time to write the question in your own words instead of pasting it directly from some exercise instruction page. This would give us some clue to what extend you have understood the task.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the house cost, add the initial cost

```
initial_cost
```

to the fuel cost for five years,

```
YEARS = 5
initial_cost + YEARS * annual_fuel_cost
```

then add the taxes for five years. Taxes for one year are computed by multiplying the tax rate by the initial cost.

```
initial_cost + YEARS * annual_fuel_cost + YEARS * initial_cost * tax_rate
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start by reading the basics at python.org.

Then you just do `T=A+B*5+A*C*5` for each of your data sets.

Finally consult your lab and lecture notes to see how to show testing.